# Is it appropriate to ask about OCAJP 8 test specification?

Tags: feature-request, specific-question

I want to know if the OCAJP 8 (1Z0-808) real exam gives the number of correct answers to the multiple choice questions when the test is taken in the near future or recently.

I'm studying for the OCAJP 8 exam where there are 80 questions and passing score is 65 % according to [education.oracle.com](https://education.oracle.com/pls/web_prod-plq-dad/db_pages.getpage?page_id=5001&get_params=p_exam_id:1Z0-808)

It also says that the questions are multiple choice. I'm practicing mostly by answering questions from mock exams which aim to replicate the real exam question as close as possible. Now the mock exams differ where some mock exams have the multiple choice question and information how many answers are correct.

For example, "select 2 answers" from typically 5 answers. That makes the test much easier if I know how many answers are correct.

After speaking with two local test centers where I can take the test, they confirm that I can book a test date and that it is the right test (1Z0-808) but they couldn't answer about the test itself when I was wondering if the actual real test now in January or in February will have questions with additional information how many answers are correct.

I wonder if there is a way to find out. Maybe somebody took the test recently and knows or might know by some other means if the mock exams make me overconfident by giving my the number of correct answers.

Is this question appropriate for this site or somewhere else in the SE network (maybe software recommendations) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is off-topic here. We do not provide support for products and services from other companies. Questions like this should be directed to the creators and maintainers of the test, since they are the only ones who can provide a correct, up-to-date and authoritative answer.